# Why does Pillow raise AttributeError 'Image' has no attribute 'open' when I use tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, python-import

I have been trying to create this piece that changes all of the white pixels in an image to the hex value of the current background but I cannot get past the error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'
```

I have installed many of the PIP/pillow/PIL packages and I'm not even sure if this is the problem.

This is my code that reproduces the error:

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys
from PIL import Image
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *
import time

# ...

# List of image filenames
images = ["personal progress.png", "settings.png", "stopwatch.png"]

# Loop through each image
for img_filename in images:
    # Load the image using PIL
    img = Image.open(img_filename)  # AttributeError raised here
```

Comment: Please show import statement

Comment: From PIL import Image

Answer (score 3):

You have conflicting imports.

Both of these imports

```
from PIL import Image

from tkinter import *
```

attempt to bind the global variable `Image`. The first one binds it to the `PIL.Image` module, and then the re-second binds it to the `tkinter.Image` type.

To fix this, remove the glob import `from tkinter import *` and access `tkinter` items through your `import tkinter as tk` import.

In the future, you might want to avoid glob imports altogethor to avoid this kind of issue. See also [Why is `import *` bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/11082165)

Answer (score -1):

The error

```
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'
```

says that you're trying to call `open` on a type object (not the module object you'd expect).

Without seeing your actual imports, I can only guess that type is the [`PIL.Image.Image`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image) class that Pillow provides. The actual [`open`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) function is a global function on the `Image` *module* `PIL.Image`.

Most likely, you need to change an import from

```
from PIL.Image import Image
```

to

```
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: I should have included the import statements but regardless this is what my imports were anyway.

Comment: @unreal8usher Do [edit] your question to include _all_ imports. In particular, are you using any glob imports?